# Can image be displayed in JavaScript Alertbox

Tags: javascript, dom

Is it possible to display image in the JavaScript Alertbox. If yes, please code it.

Answer (score 3):

No, the standard `alert()` in JavaScript is handled by the browser and doesn't have any customization available in code.  You can, however, use something like the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) to create custom alert overlays.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the one displayed using the [`window.alert()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.alert) method, then NO, it's text-only (no HTML, too.)

Answer (score 1):

The **alert** triggers the browsers default alert box. Its beahvior cant be changed.

If you want to display custom error messages, you should try make it without **alert** command.

Theres a lot of ways to do this, the easier way is using some jQuery plugin.

Like this:

http://beckelman.net/demo/more-jquery-alert-dialogs-demo/

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance; if  you want this, you have to dive in a vast sea of coding. Being a webmaster, i suggest you that on any event (e.g onmouseover , onmouseout , onload ) you load a different webpage, and give it's target parent and make the background of the page translucent (if you don't know how, use this code on the background color: the color is `rgba(10,10,10,0.5)` you can increase or decrease it's opacity  on the last digit, that's 0.5 - it is medium; if you put the value 1 then you will get opaque) then make its body and enter the script that after few seconds redirect this page to the parent page!!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Samad. Please, please, please use proper punctuation and capitalization. And by "bag", do you mean "background"?